# Как отправить данные, которые пришли в гугл-форм?

Tags: php, javascript, алгоритм, google-forms

Пользователи заполняют гугл-формы и нажимают отправить. 
Форма не вставлена на сайте. Заполняют напрямую с сервера гугл. (вставить на свой сайт не могу)
Вопрос: Как можно получать эти данные и отправлять их на мой сервер? 
Подскажите, куда копать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Данные заполненной формы падают в Google SpreadSheet, прикреплённый к этой форме. К этой таблице можно прикрепить скрипт на JavaScript, который в т.ч. может запускаться по событию поступления новой записи.

В этом скрипте можно делать с данными что угодно: отправлять себе на почту, слать на сервер, распределять по другим листам в этом же «файле». [Документация](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/).

---

В открытом SpreadSheet'е, в меню "Tools" есть пункт "Script Editor...":
[image: Script Editor...]

---

Появится редактор скриптов. Там создайте ф-ю, напр. `onFormSubmit(e)`:
[image: onFormSubmit]

---

В этой функции можно получить новую появившуюся строку и что-то сделать с её содержимым:

```
if( e  &&  e.range) {
  values = e.range.getValues();
  theNewRow = values[0]; // новая строка как массив
}
```

Остаётся назначить эту функцию обработчиком события отправки формы в Current Project's Triggers (иконка часов в тулбаре):
[image: Event triggers]

Далее данные можете [отправить письмом](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/), или ajax-запросом запостить на ваш сервер.